# Doctrine ChoiceType how to change values based on existing data in entity

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a form in a Symfony 3 CRM for Horse Rider Camps, which has a Doctrine ChoiceType field, with the option of whether to select if an attendee of the Camp is a Non-Rider or not. However, the Camp has a limit to the amount of Non-Riders allowed in the Camp so I need to be able to disable the 'Yes' option of the Non-Rider drop down and, ideally, replace it with a disabled value of "The limit has been reached for this camp" or something similar.

Here is the entry for the field:

```
$builder->add('non_rider', ChoiceType::class,
    array(
        'label' => 'Is Non-Rider',
        'required' => true,
        'placeholder' => '-- Please select --',
        'choices' => array(
            'Yes' => 1,
            'No' => 0
        ),
        'label_attr' => array(
            'class' => 'control-label'
        ),
        'attr' => array(
            'class' => 'form-control required'
        )
    ));
```

What I'd like is the `choices` field to read something like:

```
'choices' => array(
     'You have reached the limit' => null,
     'No' => 0
)
```

And somehow disabled the entry. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the event form to do that

[Customizing your Form Based on the Underlying Data](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#form-events-underlying-data)

Comment: The problem is more complex than that, to be honest. I see how the above works but the field values are dependent on the number of non-riders already registered. So I'd need to implement some kind of loop with a count and then refer to another table to get the allowed limit to be able to determine what to add